# My mongoose code is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose code is not working. I want to push new users to the Group using findOneAndUpdate but it is not working, the code for GroupSchema, adding of new members using mongoose and the code of UserSchema is given below. The modules I have used are

```
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.12.10",
"typescript": "^4.2.4"
"@types/express": "^4.17.11",
"@types/node": "^15.6.0",
"nodemon": "^2.0.7"
```

Express Code

```js
app.post('/joingroup', (req:any, res:any) => {
    let grpname = req.body.groupname;
    let name = req.cookies.name;
    User.find({name: name}, (err:any,data)=> {
        console.log(data,err)
        Group.findOneAndUpdate({name: grpname}, {
            $push: {
                members: data[0]._id
            }
        })
    })
    res.redirect("/profile");
})
```

Group Schema

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const groupSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    topic: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "casual"
    },
    admin: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    members: [ {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
}, {timestamps: true});

const Group = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);
export default Group;
```

User Schema

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
})
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)
export default User;
```

Comment: How is your code "not working"? Any errors, attempts to debug etc?
btw. for updates better use `document.save()`

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working I tried with both local installation of mongodb and cloud version of mongodb(Mongodb Atlas)

Comment: Add the rest of your code. Also, add error message from `console.log()` if there is some.

Comment: Here is the full code:
https://gist.github.com/IronManCool001/12519e79ad92fa4f1ea6bbb0e7b91b3c